# Why does everything appear backwards when using orthographic projection?

Tags: camera, projection, webgl

I may not be calculating my orthographic projection matrix properly. What can I do to ensure that my scene renders correctly when using orthographic projection?

The rendering order appears to be backwards too (note the grid and how it appears half ontop, as if the z-buffer from the correct direction was being used). Disabling culling fixes things, but the view is still backwards.

Perspective:

[image: Perspective Projection]

Orthographic:

[image: Orthographic Projection]

Matrix code for reference:

```
    Matrix4.createFrustum = function(left, right, bottom, top, near, far, result) {
        if (typeof result === 'undefined') {
            result = new Matrix4();
        }

        var re = result.elements;
        var x = 2 * near / (right - left);
        var y = 2 * near / (top - bottom);

        var a = (right + left) / (right - left);
        var b = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
        var c = - (far + near) / (far - near);
        var d = - 2 * far * near / (far - near);

        re[0] = x; re[4] = 0; re[8]  = a; re[12] = 0;
        re[1] = 0; re[5] = y; re[9]  = b; re[13] = 0;
        re[2] = 0; re[6] = 0; re[10] = c; re[14] = d;
        re[3] = 0; re[7] = 0; re[11] =-1; re[15] = 0;

        return result;
    };

    Matrix4.createPerspective = function(fov, aspect, near, far, result) {
        if (typeof result === 'undefined') {
            result = new Matrix4();
        }

        var ymax = near * Math.tan(fov * Math.PI / 360);
        var ymin = - ymax;
        var xmin = ymin * aspect;
        var xmax = ymax * aspect;

        Matrix4.createFrustum(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, near, far, /*out*/ result);

        return result;
    };

    Matrix4.createOrthographic = function(left, right, top, bottom, near, far, result) {
        if (typeof result === 'undefined') {
            result = new Matrix4();
        }

        var re = result.elements;
        var w = right - left;
        var h = top - bottom;
        var p = far - near;

        var x = ( right + left ) / w;
        var y = ( top + bottom ) / h;
        var z = ( far + near ) / p;

        re[0] =2/w;  re[4] = 0;   re[8]  = 0;   re[12] =-x;
        re[1] = 0;   re[5] =2/h;  re[9]  = 0;   re[13] =-y;
        re[2] = 0;   re[6] = 0;   re[10] =-2/p; re[14] =-z;
        re[3] = 0;   re[7] = 0;   re[11] = 0;   re[15] = 1;

        return result;
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess but if looks like you are using a Left-handed coordinate system and a Right-Handed Coordinate system together.... If you have an option to `Matrix4.createOrthographicLH` or `Matrix4.createOrthographicRH` or something like that try it and see what happens.

You could also try flipping the values in `Matrix4.createOrthographic` for `top` & `bottom`.

Those are all guesses, to do more I would need to see how you are calculating the values for `left`, `right`, `top` & `bottom` as well as how you are generating the `Perspective View matrix`?

--------  Edit -----------

Looking at it I think you need to do this:  `var h = bottom - top;`

top - bottom is going to give you a negative number.

Comment: I have added the perspective matrix functions as well

Comment: Switching the order on `h` totally did the trick! Thanks!